# can you suggest any 10 lined fable

Tags: littérature

I have a test tomorrow and I have to write a fable. Ideally, it should be a 10 line fable but a 15 line can do. So can you suggest any simple fable which is easy to learn and possibly doesn't exceed 15 lines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the french language as such but about poetry

Comment: Well I want a french fable(poem), I thought that would be related to French literature

Comment: @user2468338  Look at poets like Rimbaud, Verlaine (search *sonnets* text) or more recent Prévert (book : Paroles)

Comment: Although I don't object to helping for homework if questions are asked in a way that fits *French Language*, here we are not faced with a request for help, but for cheating. Do you really think  user2468338 that your teacher/examiner won't notice that you have "borrowed" someone else's work (and published work to boot) when they ask you to **write** a fable? Do you really think teachers and examiners are that dumb?

Comment: Bravo @ Laure. @ user2468338: "do your homework". (teacher's advice).